# JSON.parse invalid character with valid JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json

So, I have an object whose properties also contain json strings within them. When serializing this object, this is the string I get:

```
[{
    "template": 1,
    "action_json": "{\"id\":\"1\",\"action\":\"An action for all of IT!\",\"date_agreed\":\"2018-08-10\",\"complete_by\":\"2018-08-31\",\"responsible_departments\":[\"8\"],\"responsible_employees\":[\"1629\",\"112\",\"1374\"],\"priority\":\"High\"}",
    "template_json": "{\"columns\":[{\"id\":\"id\",\"title\":\"Task Number\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"auto\"},{\"id\":\"action\",\"title\":\"Action Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"longtext\"},{\"id\":\"date_agreed\",\"title\":\"Date Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"complete_by\",\"title\":\"Complete By\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_departments\",\"title\":\"Responsible Departments\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_employees\",\"title\":\"Responsible Employees\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"priority\",\"title\":\"Priority\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\",\"options\":[\"High\",\"Medium\",\"Low\"]}]}"
}, {
    "template": 1,
    "action_json": "{\"id\":\"1\",\"action\":\"Action numero uno\",\"date_agreed\":\"2018-08-10\",\"complete_by\":\"2018-08-10\",\"responsible_departments\":[\"8\"],\"responsible_employees\":[\"112\"],\"priority\":\"High\"}",
    "template_json": "{\"columns\":[{\"id\":\"id\",\"title\":\"Task Number\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"auto\"},{\"id\":\"action\",\"title\":\"Action Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"longtext\"},{\"id\":\"date_agreed\",\"title\":\"Date Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"complete_by\",\"title\":\"Complete By\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_departments\",\"title\":\"Responsible Departments\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_employees\",\"title\":\"Responsible Employees\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"priority\",\"title\":\"Priority\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\",\"options\":[\"High\",\"Medium\",\"Low\"]}]}"
}]
```

Which is fine, this is valid JSON.

The problem arises when I try to create a JavaScript object by parsing this string (using PHP):

```
echo "<script>
    var employeeActions = JSON.parse('".json_encode($employeeActions)."');
</script>";
```

And then I get:

> JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:33

When inspecting the page once it's loaded, here is what is echoed through my PHP script:

```
<script>
    var employeeActions = JSON.parse('[{"template":1,"action_json":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"action\":\"An action for all of IT!\",\"date_agreed\":\"2018-08-10\",\"complete_by\":\"2018-08-31\",\"responsible_departments\":[\"8\"],\"responsible_employees\":[\"1629\",\"112\",\"1374\"],\"priority\":\"High\"}","template_json":"{\"columns\":[{\"id\":\"id\",\"title\":\"Task Number\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"auto\"},{\"id\":\"action\",\"title\":\"Action Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"longtext\"},{\"id\":\"date_agreed\",\"title\":\"Date Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"complete_by\",\"title\":\"Complete By\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_departments\",\"title\":\"Responsible Departments\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_employees\",\"title\":\"Responsible Employees\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"priority\",\"title\":\"Priority\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\",\"options\":[\"High\",\"Medium\",\"Low\"]}]}"},{"template":1,"action_json":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"action\":\"Action numero uno\",\"date_agreed\":\"2018-08-10\",\"complete_by\":\"2018-08-10\",\"responsible_departments\":[\"8\"],\"responsible_employees\":[\"112\"],\"priority\":\"High\"}","template_json":"{\"columns\":[{\"id\":\"id\",\"title\":\"Task Number\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"auto\"},{\"id\":\"action\",\"title\":\"Action Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"longtext\"},{\"id\":\"date_agreed\",\"title\":\"Date Agreed\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"complete_by\",\"title\":\"Complete By\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_departments\",\"title\":\"Responsible Departments\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"responsible_employees\",\"title\":\"Responsible Employees\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\"},{\"id\":\"priority\",\"title\":\"Priority\",\"default\":true,\"type\":\"option\",\"options\":[\"High\",\"Medium\",\"Low\"]}]}"}]');
</script>
```

Comment: Would you print $employeeActions and place here that string? it looks like it is different then provided by you.

Comment: The first string I show is a serialized version of `$employeeActions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you output from `json_encode` will be passed through the parser for JavaScript string literals before it gets passed through `JSON.parse`.

Since JSON and JS string literals use the same escape characters, this will break it! You are mashing up `'` characters and data to try to construct a JS string literal programmatically, but the data includes characters with special meaning in JS.

> ```
> "{\"i
> ```

That shows character 33. The JS string literal `\"` will be parsed putting an unescaped `"` in the string.

Forget about using `JSON.parse`. Forget about trying to pass JSON to the browser. Remember that JSON and JavaScript literal syntax are more or less the same thing:

```
<script>
var employeeActions = <?php echo json_encode($employeeActions); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: I see. Wonderful! Thanks :)